# Image Not Appearing when AJAX Call Returns

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, image

I have this AJAX search functionality that searches through a list of files in a table and then updates the results according to the user's input. Now, I have a download button(which is an image) next to the file name in the table that enables the user to download the file. The problem is that when the AJAX call returns it is simply refusing to display the image. I don't know if i have a syntax error or if that is simply just not feasible. Code is here:

```
echo "<tr>

<td class='tlong'>".$state['title']."</td>

<td style='font-size:11px;' class=''>".$state['filesize']."
<a style='padding-left:px;' href='../downloads/".$state["filename"]."'><img src='../images/footer/downloadImage.png' alt='' style='width:10px;height:10px;'/></a>
</td>

</tr>";
}
```

This is the code inside the AJAX method. Im first pulling the title from the database, then the file size, then its supposed to show the image which enables the user to download that file next to it. But the image just doesnt show. It is however putting the alt text when I specify one. Any ideas peeps?

Comment: what do you see in the console when you do `console.log(data)` in the `success` function?

Comment: As a design preference, I would suggest you have PHP return raw data and have the client parse it and do things with it.

Comment: If the image is not displaying but its alt text is, it means that the image path cannot be found.

Comment: Matanya I am retrieving results correctly and displaying the wanted files in the tables. But the image just does not load. 

Waleed I've checked the path countless times, I've even put the image in the same folder of the AJAX method. No luck.

Comment: R U sure it is not a CSS issue? that is, the image is loaded, but it remains hidden

Comment: Nope, turned out to be a path issue. Mr Semsem's clarification solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check The path of image's src and the page that run the AJAX request. In other word, does the image rendered properly if you directly inserted it into that page?

```
// In the page that run AJAX
<img src='../images/footer/downloadImage.png' />
```

Suppose the following directory structure:

```
request.html
js/ajax_target.html
js/imgs/downloadImage.png
```

if the downloadImage is going to be rendered in ajax_target.html its src would be *imgs/downloadImage.png*, but if it would be rendered from request.html it should be *js/imgs/downloadImage.png*

Comment: I quadruple checked that. Even put images in the same directory of the AJAX request. Nothing.

Comment: Yes the image is rendering correctly when it is set into the page. When the page initially loads it has all the files laid out in the database with the image next to them. It disappears when I initiate the AJAX request.

Comment: My AJAX call is as follows:


  function getStates(value){
    $.post("update/getStates.php", {partialState:value}, function(data){
      $(".results").html(data);
    });
  }

Where do You suggest I put js/imgs/downloadImage.png?

Comment: @Frisbetarian Never, I did not suggest to change your directory structure, I just supposed an example of the effect of the images path and the img tag in each different page.

Comment: AHA! Thank you! I did not think of it that way. I was pulling the image path according to the location of my ajax method, not from where I was calling the method. Very insightful, you have my thanks friend :)